Cannot fetch the customSecurityAttributes data from Entra ID user Profile using Microsoft Graph API in Dotnet Webapi
I cannot fetch the customSecurityAttributes data from Entra ID user Profile. I have created a dotnet 8 webapi to pull the user details. it pulls the other properties but in case of customSecurityAttributes, it only pulls the attribute set name i.e. devDetails, with the null value (no details about custom attribute names and values). Please help.
        [HttpGet("specificcust/{UUID}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserDetailsCust(string UUID)
{
    var result = await _graphClient.Users[UUID].GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
        {
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "customSecurityAttributes" };
        });

        if (result.CustomSecurityAttributes != null && result.CustomSecurityAttributes.AdditionalData != null)
        {
            foreach (var attribute in result.CustomSecurityAttributes.AdditionalData)
            {
                var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(attribute.Value);
                Console.WriteLine($"{attribute.Key}: {json}");
                return Ok(json);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No custom security attributes found.");
        }
    return Ok(result.ToString());
}

My Service client:
public class GraphApiService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphClient;
    public GraphServiceClient GraphClient => _graphClient;

public GraphApiService(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
    _graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient();
}

private GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient()
{
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        _configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"],
        _configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"],
        _configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"]
    );

    return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, 
    new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
}

}
My output:
devDetails: {}

Edit:

Edit:


Edit 2:
It worked with Node JS (Express JS)
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const { Client } = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
CUS_PORT = 3500;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

if (!globalThis.fetch) {
  globalThis.fetch = fetch;
}

app.use(express.json({ limit: "5mb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const tenantId = "";
const clientId = "";
const clientSecret = "";
const UUID = "";

const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

const client = Client.init({
  authProvider: async (done) => {
    try {
      const accessToken = await credential.getToken(
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
      );
      done(null, accessToken.token);
    } catch (error) {
      done(error, null);
    }
  },
});

app.get("/getData", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // const UUID = req.params.UUID;
    const result = await client
      .api(`/users/${UUID}`)
      .select("customSecurityAttributes")
      .get();

    res.status(200).send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});

app.listen(CUS_PORT, () => {
  console.log(
    `API is running on ${CUS_PORT} port started at ${new Date().toDateString()} ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`
  );
});

Result:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(customSecurityAttributes)/$entity",
  "customSecurityAttributes": {
    "devDetails": {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.customSecurityAttributeValue",
      "devLocation": "Canada",
      "devOrAdmin": 1,
      "devLab": "BIRG"
    }
  }
}


Can you paste the screenshot of the user customsecurityattribute from portal?

To get custom security attribute assignments, the calling principal must be assigned the Attribute Assignment Reader or Attribute Assignment Administrator role and must be granted the CustomSecAttributeAssignment.Read.All or CustomSecAttributeAssignment.ReadWrite.All permission.

Thank you for the response. My registered app in Entra ID has the access as
CustomSecAttributeAssignment.ReadWrite.All and
CustomSecAttributeDefinition.ReadWrite.All.

pasted the screenshot in edit

So you want the assigned values in the output?

I want the attribute name and value in output. I am only getting the attribute set name in output for now.

Sure will post the answer

Note that: To fetch the custom security attribute assignments for a user, you need to assign the Attribute Assignment Reader role to the application and grant CustomSecAttributeAssignment.Read.All API permission to the application. Refer this MsDoc
The user has custom security attribute assignments like below:

Grant CustomSecAttributeAssignment.Read.All API permission:

Assign the Attribute Assignment Reader role to the application

Now for sample I used the below code and, got the custom security attribute assignments of a user successfully:
class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string clientId = "ClientID"; 
        string clientSecret = "Secret"; 
        string tenantId = "TenantID"; 

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);
        string userId = "UserID"; 

        // Fetch custom security attributes
        await GetCustomSecurityAttributes(graphClient, userId);
    }

    private static async Task GetCustomSecurityAttributes(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await graphClient.Users[userId].GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "customSecurityAttributes" };
            });

            if (result.CustomSecurityAttributes != null && result.CustomSecurityAttributes.AdditionalData != null)
            {
                foreach (var attribute in result.CustomSecurityAttributes.AdditionalData)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{attribute.Key}: {attribute.Value}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No custom security attributes found.");
            }
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error fetching user details: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}



UPDATE Try the below:
 private static async Task GetCustomSecurityAttributes(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            
            var result = await graphClient.Users[userId].GetAsync();
            if (result.CustomSecurityAttributes != null && result.CustomSecurityAttributes.AdditionalData != null)
            {
                
                foreach (var attribute in result.CustomSecurityAttributes.AdditionalData)
                {
                    if (attribute.Value is Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Serialization.UntypedObject)
                    {
                        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(attribute.Value);
                        Console.WriteLine($"{attribute.Key}: {json}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{attribute.Key}: {attribute.Value}");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No custom security attributes found.");
            }
        }


Thank you for your efforts. followed this code, but my output is,
devDetails: Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Serialization.UntypedObject

Can you paste your full code

Check the updated answer

still a blank output inside attribute set name, added complete code in edit

Did you try my exact code?

btw, i has given the permission to API. but I could not able to find the role assignment for the application.

You have to assign role to the application to fetch the data. Go to Microsoft Entra roles and administrators -> Search Attribute Assignment Reader role and assign to the application

Try assigning the role and fetching it will work

somehow, i can only assign that role to users or groups, not to the applications. pasted 2 screenshots in edit. maybe I will fix that first and then try again. Also, getting this output with your code :- devDetails: {}

Yes search the application name you will get the application and assign role and after that you will get the results

Did you search in the search bar with application name?

Any update @SaurabhKulkarni

I will check in couple hours. (Canadian time zone)

Sure let me know if it works:)

Still not able to find the option to assign a role to an application. Created a custom role with all permissions added. Surprisingly, I can now even add new custom attributes from my API into the user profile, but still no read. I will try further.

I wrote a new code in Node JS (Express JS), and it worked. I am not sure why dotnet is not providing the output. The issue is with parsing the result to get the actual data.
Updated code pasted in edit.

Update: Finally, it worked, but I had to use httpclient and provide the endpoints in dotnet. it's not that annoying. so it's fine.

Glad to know that it worked:)
